# Directory to store secure file

Tags: php, security, passwords, client-certificates

I have a website hosted on ASP.NET server and using wordpress to build my site. I've extended its functionalities using PHP code. At which directory do I store secure files such as (passwords and certificate.pem)?

My server has the following structure:

```
-/
   -/mywebsite.com
       -/data
       -/logs
       -/wwwroot
            -/wp-admin
            -/wp-content
            -/wp-includes
```

I understand that ASP.NET has a file called web.config file that is secure and stored at `wwwroot`. What's something equivalent using PHP?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Is `-/website.com/data` and `-/website.com/logs` publicly accessible? If not, you could create a new folder in `-website.com/` to house the files.

`/etc/` is a popular place for these types of files.

Comment: I'm using a shared host so I'm not seeing `/etc/`.  All the directories I can see are the one I wrote above. The disadvantage here is that I don't have a hacker's mind to know what directory is accessible by others. I can put it in `/mywebsite.com/data` but is it really secure?

Comment: Assuming that the hackers aren't executing arbitrary code on your server, yes it is hidden.

Comment: What does `-/website.com/data` do? Is that where your database is keeping stuff?

Comment: I think when I perform db backup from the cPanel, it gets stored under `/data` but now it's just empty. So I guess is this a secure place.  Also, under `/wwwroot`, Wordpress place a file called `wp-config.php` which also contains database password. So I guess `wwwroot` is also a safe place?

Comment: I highly doubt that `wwwroot` is safe. Try creating a test file called `test.txt`, put some content like "Hello World" in there, and go to http://mywebsite.com/test.txt

Comment: Humm, after creating test.txt file, I can actually read the content from this url `mywebsite.com/test.txt`. So why do wordpress store password in `wp-config.php`? It doesn't look like I should put my certificate.pem file under `wwwroot`